# How to compare @NO and @YES with elegance and without risk of false positives/negatives?

Tags: ios, objective-c, comparison, boolean

I want to use bool literals like

```
if (condition == @NO) {

}
else if (condition == @YES) {

{
```

When I try this, XCode wants me to use NSNumber methods to compare, like isEqualTo. Is there a simpler way to do this (without isEqualTo)? If I can't, should I use isEqualTo, isEqualToValue, or isEqualToNumber?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What is `condition`? Is it a `BOOL` or an `NSNumber`?

---

If `condition` is a `BOOL`, then you don't want to use `@NO` or `@YES` at all. You want to say

```
if (condition) // test if condition is true

if (!condition) // test if condition is false

if (condition == NO) // same as previous, based on personal preference
```

Note that you should never say

```
if (condition == YES)
```

because `BOOL` isn't actually restricted to `0` and `1` as values, it can hold anything in `char`, so if `condition` accidentally holds, say, `3`, then `if (condition)` and `if (condition == YES)` would behave differently.

---

If `condition` is an `NSNumber`, then you still don't want to use `@NO` and `@YES`. You just want to convert it to a `BOOL` using `-boolValue`, as in

```
if ([condition boolValue]) // test if condition is true

if (![condition boolValue]) // test if condition is false

if ([condition boolValue] == NO) // same as previous, based on personal preference
```

---

The basic takeaway here is, don't use `@NO` and `@YES` literals for comparisons. It's pointless, and inelegant, since all you'd be able to do with them is convert them back into `BOOL`s.

Comment: Note that !condition and condition == NO are **not** the same.  There is one edge case.  Let's say condition is 256.  This would overflow into 0 and be equal to `NO` since it is simply a signed char.  However, the `!` operator returns a C boolean, which is explicitly defined by the C standard to be true for all values other than zero.  So the `BOOL` would be `NO` and the `bool` would be `true`

Comment: Nevermind about that, the above example seems to work itself.  The case that bit me is slightly different.  For certain cases of BOOL (namely the 8-bit overflow) (flag) and (flag == NO) will both be false.

Comment: You can also use the Objective-C 2.0 notation for accessors for boolValue

Comment: @borrrden: `!flag` and `flag == NO` are, by definition, identical.

Comment: @KevinBallard Yes, you are correct, sorry that I wrote that but I've had trouble with BOOLs before and I thought it was related, but it wasn't.  The case I had trouble with was when I expected a `YES` value (and for a `bool` it would have worked correctly) but instead I got a `NO` value.  The solution was to either cast to `bool` or use !!condition (double not operator that implicitly casts to `bool`).  I thought for sure it would be related to this but it turns out not to be.

Comment: Remember that BOOLs are stored as NSNumbers in Core-Data

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the data type of `condition` is `BOOL`, then you want:

```
if (condition) {
    // true (YES)
} else {
    // false (NO)
}
```

If condition is an `NSNumber` then use:

```
if ([condition boolValue]) {
    // true (YES)
} else {
    // false (NO)
}
```

If `condition` is based on some arbitrary numbers then treat `0` as `NO` and treat non-zero as `YES`.

Again, if `condition` is an `NSNumber` then do:

```
if ([condition intValue]) {
    // non-zero - true (YES)
} else {
    // zero - false (NO)
}
```

**Update**: Based on the following comment from the OP:

> Condition is a bool, like if (myView.frame.size.height == 30)

This implies that the actual question wanted to do checks something like:

```
if ((myView.frame.size.height == 30) == YES)
```

This is very unusual. The proper thing to do is:

```
if (myView.frame.size.height == 30) {
    // true - height is 30
} else {
    // false - height is not 30
}
```

There is no need to worry about false positives or negatives. The condition is either true or it isn't. There is no 3rd possibility. If the condition gives the wrong result then the solution is to fix the condition.

Comment: What numbers trigger @NO or @YES?

Comment: None directly. If `condition` is created from `[NSNumber numberWithBool:]` then you compare against `@YES` or `@NO`.

Comment: Comparing to `YES` may be problematic in [some cases](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/564-bools-sharp-corners/). And +1 for not using dot syntax for a non-property method call.

Comment: @yourfriendzak Notice all of the options. This is because you haven't been clear. What type is `condition`? How have you created its value?

Comment: @CarlVeazey Yes, until we get more details about the type of `condition` and how its value is set, it's difficult to nail down the proper solution.

Comment: A few bad answers in here. Never *ever* say `condition == YES`, because `BOOL` isn't a true boolean value and therefore may have a non-zero value that's not the same as `YES`. Similarly `[condition isEqual:@YES]` would only work if `condition` was constructed from `YES` to begin with; if it's a non-zero non-`YES` value, that will also fail. And of course `[condition boolValue] == YES` is also bad.

Comment: @KevinBallard If `BOOL` values are only used with `YES` or `NO` then what I have is just fine. Personally, anyone that assigns any other value to a `BOOL` variable is asking for trouble (and it using it wrong). What I have posted will never be a problem in my own code because I only use the proper values with `BOOL` values.

Comment: @KevinBallard Once the OP chimes in here and tells us what he really has, more precise answers can be given.

Comment: @rmaddy: Regardless of what you do personally, it's a really bad idea to give out advice like this to other people. The simple fact is, `if (boolValue == YES)` is not the same thing as `if (boolValue)`, with the former unexpectedly evaluating the condition to `0` in some cases.

Comment: @KevinBallard I only use `if (value)` or `if (!value)` myself. Again, until the OP chimes in, my answer is tailored to the style of the original code.

Comment: @rmaddy: It's still bad advice. Code that behaves correctly trumps matching style every time.

Comment: Condition is a bool, like if (myView.frame.size.height == 30)

Comment: @yourfriendzak So `condition` isn't a variable of type `BOOL` or `NSNumber`? Now your question makes no sense. Why would you do something like `if ((myView.frame.size.height == 30) == YES)`? Is that what you are really asking?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, I wanted to evaluate nested expressions. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @yourfriendzak Please see the update I added to the end of my original answer. Does this now answer your question?

Comment: @rmaddy It's people like you that make SO such an amazing place.

Answer (score 2):

You can save @NO in a dictionary because @NO is an object. You cannot save NO in a dictionary. 
So use @NO.boolValue when needed. For example:

```
NSDictionary *userSetting = (NSDictionary *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"user"];
//Suppose you have done: userSetting[@"canWriteCode"] = @YES;
if ([userSetting[@"canWriteCode"] boolValue])
    [self helloProgrammer];
```

Answer (score -1):

Is `condition` a `NSNumber`? If so just use:

```
if(condition.integerValue) {
    //condition is YES
} else {
    //condition is NO
}
```

And by the way, a value of 0 represents NO, any other value is YES;

Answer (score -2):

You can use `@YES.boolValue` and `@NO.boolValue`.

So, to compare against bool literal you can write something like (given the fact that `condition` is `BOOL`)

```
if (condition == @NO.boolValue) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. If `condition` is an `NSNumber` and the OP doesn't want to use `isEqual:`, then this is actually one possible solution.

Comment: Why would you ever say `@NO.boolValue` instead of just saying `NO`?

Comment: > I want to use bool literals

Comment: @KevinBallard Personally I wouldn't but it is valid.

Comment: @maddy Valid yes, but just as pointless as converting NO to a string "nooohoooo" and parsing that string back to a BOOL, right?

Comment: The OP wanted to use bool literals and I provide a solution. I don't see any actual reason for this answer to be downvoted, no matter how "pointless" it is, since it is answering the actual question. If you think the question was wrong, downvote the question instead.

Comment: @anticyclope I didn't personally downvote, I save downvoting for really bad answers. But I supposed you were downvoted because people want the answers here to be "correct" in the sense of "a good way to do it", and not just "technically correct yet somewhat pointless".